# Ordering an SQLite result by assigned column name

Tags: sqlite

I have the following:

```
select count(*) as 'count',
    layer as 'layer'
    from [tms_records]
    group by layer
    ORDER BY count DESC
```

This works perfectly within [Sqliteman](http://sqliteman.com/) (SQLite version 3.6.19), however in [SQLiteStudio](http://sqlitestudio.pl/) (SQLite version 3.7.16.1), I get an error:
`Error while executing query: no such column: count`enter code here`

This is referring to the ORDER BY which is using the assigned name `count`.

So which of these applications is correct? I'd have expected if it's done by the SQLite engine it should be the same in both. Or at least the older one to be broken and the newer one working, but it's the newer one that's not working. If I'm not supposed to do the ORDER BY like that, how am I meant to do it?

I've tried reading - http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html - however it goes over my head; and the term "AS" (upper case) doesn't appear in it anyway.

Thanks.

Comment: Search again. "AS" appears in `result-column`, which is in `select-core`, which is in `select-stmt` in the documentation you referred to.

Comment: I have run this query on SQLite Database Browser 2.0 without issue, using SQLite engine 3.6.18, if that's of any help.

Comment: (also run without issue on command line sqlite3 3.8.0.2). I suggest you try running your command using sqlite command line interface

Comment: @njzk2 - thanks. I guess that means it's a bug then. I see the "AS" now - it's part of an image, I was using text search. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntax etc is correct in query. It's a bug in SQLiteStudio - http://bugs.sqlitestudio.pl/ - bug 2514.